# Degree of blow up of a smooth projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, blowup

Let $X$ be a smooth projective hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a finite set of closed points in $X$. Let $X'$ be the blow up of $X$ at these points. Then,

$1)$ Is there a natural/canonical choice of a very ample line bundle on $X'$?

$2)$ What are the possible degrees of $X'$ (depending on the embedding into a projective space)?

If someone could suggest a good reference on blow up of smooth projective surfaces and their embeddings into projective space, that would be very helpful.

`

Comment: I had [a similar question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77562/ample-divisors-on-blown-up-projective-space) once, and at least part of your first question is addressed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9410011).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain: your comment seems like it would make a good answer.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: I will do that then. I did not want to discourage people from giving a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had [a similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77562/ample-divisors-on-blown-up-projective-space) once, and at least part of your first question is addressed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9410011).